# How do I create a specific login page for a specific user?

Tags: theme-development, users, login

I wonder, how can I create two separate login pages for two specific users?

Say, for example: I have two users on my site. Admin and Viewer.

On my site's frontend I want to create two different login pages. One login form for Admin only and one login form for Viewer only. I want them to be on a different url too.

I hope you could help me with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to locate/style them or do you want for accounts to be _unable to login_ altogether with the "wrong" form?

Comment: ah nope. I want to create two login forms. one for admin users and one for viewer users

Answer (score 1):

On-topic answer:

You can just put `<?php wp_login_form(); ?>` into any of your theme templates to render a login form on the front end of your site.

Or make your own shortcode `[loginform]` by putting this into your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_242473_login_form() {
    return wp_login_form( 'echo' => false );
}

add_shortcode( 'loginform', 'wpse_242473_login_form' );
```

Comment: Hi Andy,  how do i specify the login to restrict only Viewer role users can login using the form? I will make two login forms . for admins and for viewers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is the function [`wp_login_form( [ /* array of arguments */ ] )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/), which displays a login form that you can put into every template. When you look at the internals, you will see that the forms action points to:

```
esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) )
```

…(at least if you did not use the `$args['redirect']` argument). This means that `wp-login.php` handles the sign on. Now you have multiple options:

1. You can use the arguments for the function or globally set the filter `login_form_defaults`, which allows you to alter the default values, like `redirect`, which per default points to the current site:

   ```
   ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
   ```

   Then you can use a filter to redirect based on the role (or perform a log out if the logged in user role did not match the role that you want to allow logging in from this template):

   ```
    apply_filters( 'login_redirect', $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user );
   ```
2. You scratch that idea as you can not determine the difference between an *admin* and a *guest* as you do not know the role of a user *before* they logged in.

Answer (score 0):

For a custom register user form, you can use [Advanced Custom Fields to create a front-end form](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/).

You can set up the custom fields for the registration using ACF, and set the location rules for the field group when User Form is equal to Register, and Add/Edit.

I did something similar, hooking into the `acf/pre_save_post` filter and doing the following:

- sanitize the inputs
- register the user with `register_new_user()`, which handles the password generation and email notification
- use `wp_update_user()` and `update_user_meta()` to map the appropriate custom ACF fields to custom WP user profile fields
- set the new user's role
- use `wp_mail()` to email admin if required

Some more information on [registering a user with ACF](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/registering-new-user-with-acf/) here.

```
function my_pre_save_user( $post_id ) { 

    // If we have an email address, add the user
    // This field only exists in the new user field group
   if ( isset($_POST['acf']['add acf_field_ID here']) && !empty($_POST['acf']['add acf_field_ID here'])) {

        // sanitize our inputs
        $sanitized_email = sanitize_email( $_POST['acf']['add acf_field_ID here'] );
        $sanitized_firstname = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acf']['add acf_field_ID here'] );
        $sanitized_lastname = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acf']['add acf_field_ID here'] );
        $sanitized_contactnumber = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acf']['add acf_field_ID here'] );

        // Prepare basic user info
        $username = $sanitized_email;
        $email = $sanitized_email;
        $display_name = $sanitized_firstname .' '. $sanitized_lastname;

         // Register the user and store the ID as $user_id, handles the validation, generates random password and send email notification to user
        $user_id = register_new_user( $username, $email );

        // If we get an error (eg user already exists)
        if( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
            // Show the error
            echo 'Error: '.$user_id->get_error_message();
            // Exit
            exit;

        // Good to go
        } else {

            // get single value from post object
            $dmc_get_company_field = $_POST['acf']['add acf_field_ID here'];
            $dmc_selected_exhibitor = get_field( $dmc_get_company_field );

            // Update the new user's info
            wp_update_user( array(
                'ID' => $user_id,
                'first_name'  => $sanitized_firstname,
                'last_name'  => $sanitized_lastname,
                'display_name'  => $display_name
            ));

            // update the new users's meta
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dmc_exhibitor_company_name', $dmc_get_company_field  );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dmc_exhibitor_contact_number', $sanitized_contactnumber );

            // update user role
            $user_id_role = new WP_User( $user_id );
            $user_id_role->set_role( 'contributor' );
            $profile_link = get_edit_user_link( $user_id );

            $to = "[add email addresses here]";
            $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
            $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
            $headers[] = 'Reply-To: '. $username. ' <'. $email .'>';

            $subject = "[add email subject here]";
            $body = "[add email body here]";

            // send the email
            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

            // redirect to thankyou page
            $redirect_url = get_bloginfo('url') . '[add URL to redirect to here]';
            wp_redirect( $redirect_url );

            // exit this script
            exit;

        }

    } else {
        return $post_id;
    }

}
add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_user' );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to achieve a separate login form on a different page than the one for admins then you can easily use a plugin. There are multiple ones, free or premium.

I will list "**Custom Frontend Login Registration Form**" as I already worked with it in the past. You can reach it on WordPress Repository.

[image]

It will generate a shortcode you can use on a custom page for your **Viewer only** users. The plugin also comes with registration shortcode, so will make your visitor's life easier.

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Hi Cristian, I just tried the plugin you said. created the login form using the shortcode.  the admin can still login using the form. i want to have the form only for viewers user. i don't see any configurations for the plugin.