# How to Create a login for for subscribers only

Tags: login, forms

does anyone tried creating a login form specifically for Subscribers? meaning if the user roles are admins, contributors, authors are not able to login on that said form only subscriber users. Thanks!

Comment: By login do you mean access to the dashboard, just plain login in.

If its plain login you want, you could try to check the user role of the user who is trying to log in, if the user is not a subscriber, send them a message stating that they are not able to login and destroy their session

Comment: i think that's a good idea. do you have some code snippet on checking the user role after logging in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a specific login page for a specific user?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242631/how-do-i-create-a-specific-login-page-for-a-specific-user)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snipped. Make sure to run this code after the users are logged in

```
//To get logged in user information
$user = wp_get_current_user();
//Condition to check weather user is subscriber or not
if ( in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //The user has the "subscriber" role
}else{
 // redirect user to different section and end their session
 wp_logout(); // user is logged out
 wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) ); // user is redirected to home page
}
```

Do let me know if this works for you or not

Comment: How do i call this function?

Comment: this is how i call the login form function :

<?php jr_login_form_2( $action, $redirect); ?>

and inside that function:

Comment: `code`  function jr_login_form_2( $action = '', $redirect = '' ) {
 global $posted;

 // make sure there's the correct url
 if ( ! $action ) $action = site_url('wp-login.php');

 if ( ! $redirect ) $redirect = admin_url();

  

?>  `code'

Comment: @Sayroose This is an independent code you can use it hook it in `init` or any other hook provided by wordpress

As for function. I do not understand why you are using a it and for what purpose